# Refresh list items (not update) using PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

In SharePoint 2013 **List A**, I want to refresh value of **column A** of all items, but I don't want to make new item version when I do refreshing/update.
Column A is calculated column and it is calculating difference in time between Now() and some other date column. So it would display correct value only if user manually edit item.

I found PowerShell script that updates column A, but it will leave new item version, any chance to suggest me how can I modify it so Items won't be updated?

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://Server/ListLocation
$list = $web.Lists["ListA"]

foreach ($item in $list.Items)
{
  $item.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With function UpdateOverwriteVersion I did what I want.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://Server/ListLocation
$list = $web.Lists["ListA"]

foreach ($item in $list.Items)
{
  $item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
}
```